# Any standard Library function to compare unordered list?

Tags: java, guava

I want to compare two unordered list and currently I am doing it in the following way. Is there a better way to do this as I am repeating my code twice (for null check & then converting to a Set). Maybe there exists a library in Guava which does this?

```
public class CompareUnorderedList implements BiPredicate<Object, Object> {
    private Function<Object, Object> mapping;
    public CompareUnorderedList(Function<Object, Object> mapping) {
       this.mapping = mapping;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean test(Object o1, Object o2) {
        o1 = o1 != null ? o1 : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        o2 = o2 != null ? o2 : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

        Set<Object> firstSet = (List<Object>o1).stream().map(mapping).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Object> secondSet = (List<Object>o2).stream().map(mapping).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return firstSet.equals(secondSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the same element is present in both lists but has a different number of occurrences in each? The lists will appear equal when transformed into sets. Is that what you want?

Comment: @gdejohn It will be present only once..so set is fine in my case

Comment: If elements can't occur more than once and you don't care about order, why are you using lists at all? Please add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, because it's very confusing.

Comment: @gdejohn It is from a client library I am receiving a List. Don't have any control on the Datastructure being used there. I am comparing basically the current version of the List I have with a previous revision

Comment: Have you considered `equals()`? And if that doesn't answer your question, what *is* your question?

Comment: @EJP I tried equals and it doesn't work. What didn't you understand in my question? I have mentioned the way I attempted it. Just wanted to find out if there is a more cleaner way?

Comment: @EJP As you can see I am using a mapper.

Comment: What I don't understand in your question is what *is* your question. 'Doesn't work' is not a problem description. Do you want to (a) ignore nulls, and if so why? and (b) ignore ordering, and again if so why, and (c) ignore duplicates, and again if so why?

Comment: Umm.. I haven't said it doesn't work. I have said it works, but wanted to know if there is a better way. If both are null, I want it to be true, I don't care of ordering as both the lists are populated by human inputs and can be out of order. There are no duplicates.

Comment: **You have said exactly that.** I quote: 'I tried equals and it doesn't work.' You haven't defined 'doesn't work'. You haven't defined 'better way'. You haven't answered most of the six questions I asked you. 'If both are null' is meaningless until you define 'both'. You haven't made any other attempt to define your requirement. You haven't posted an answerable question.